# How can I have 2 gridviews in one form with same dataset, but other population?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, dataset, datasource

Here you see my code of a form with 2 gridviews. Both have the same dataset, bindingsource. The dataset which is made out of a datasource, has 2 different sql queries.
filld() and fillauswahl() filld shows in the gridview a "select distinct" query.
When the user hits the button1, the selected item from that gridview is saved in "verzeichnis1"  this var gets pasted to fillauswahl() which is
 `select* from mytable where columnx = verzeichnis1`

The problem I have is that both gridviews get filled during formload with filld() and by clicking the button with fillverzeichnis() i dont know how to seperate that!? i guess it´s very easy. Cheers and thanks

`Public Class Importverzeichnis`

```
Public verzeichnis1 As String


Private Sub Importverzeichnis_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Try
        Me.SKM2TableAdapter.Filld(Me.SLXADRIUMDEVDataSet.SKM2)

    Catch ex As System.Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In DataGridView1.SelectedCells

        verzeichnis1 = cell.Value


    Next

    Me.SKM2TableAdapter.Fillauswahl(Me.SLXADRIUMDEVDataSet.SKM2, verzeichnis1)


End Sub
End Class
```

Edit: I created a new connection a new datset and new dataadapter and now it works:

```
    Dim connectionString As String = My.Settings.SLXADRIUMDEVConnectionString
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM SKM2 where 
    Benutzerdefiniert_10 ='" & verzeichnis1 & "' "
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)


    Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)

    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    connection.Open()
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "verzeichnis")
    connection.Close()


    datagridview2.DataSource = ds
    datagridview2.DataMember = "verzeichnis"
```

but I would be more happy if can use my first dataset and my first adapter. If anyobdy knows how I can do this, I would be happy for the answer

Answer (score 0):

To me the best way would be to just pull down the data as a your normal select statement and then filter the data in your code-behind. By populating a dataset with the same data twice your just making the traffic from the database slower. However, if you wish to keep your current dataset, I would assume that there are two tables in it, one for each select. If that is the case then change:

```
datagridview2.DataSource = ds
```

to:

```
datagridview2.DataSource = ds.Tables(1) 'assumes the second table is used for this datasource
```

Comment: This is my whish. I want two tables in my dataset, for each query one. But I am jost not  fit regarding the programming. This is my first database Project.  All I did was creating the datasource pulling gridviews from the datasource toolbar into the project, and now I created that connection from above with help from google. every try to create a second table in the dataset and link it to the right sql statement failed.